# How to compress a file with shutil.make_archive in python?

Tags: python, compression

I want to compress one text file using `shutil.make_archive` command. I am using the following command:

```
shutil.make_archive('gzipped'+fname, 'gztar', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), fname))

OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/user/file.txt'
```

I tried several variants but it keeps trying to compress the whole folders. How to do it correctly?

Comment: copy file.txt to a directory and try invoking that on that directory

Comment: what directory? file.txt is in `/home/user`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shutil` can't create an archive from one file. You can use `tarfile`, instead:

```
tar = tarfile.open(fname + ".tar.gz", 'w:qz')
os.chdir('/home/user')
tar.add("file.txt")
tar.close()
```

or

```
tar = tarfile.open(fname + ".tar.gz", 'w:qz')
tar.addfile(tarfile.TarInfo("/home/user/file.txt"), "/home/user/file.txt")
tar.close()
```

Answer (score 23):

Actually [`shutil.make_archive`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive) can make one-file archive! Just pass path to target directory as `root_dir` and target filename as `base_dir`.

Try this:

```
import shutil

file_to_zip = 'test.txt'            # file to zip
target_path = 'C:\\test_yard\\'     # dir, where file is

try:
    shutil.make_archive(target_path + 'archive', 'zip', target_path, file_to_zip)
except OSError:
    pass
```

Comment: What's the minimum version for this to work? At python 2.7.6 supplying a filename as base_dir resulted in an empty zip files

Answer (score 3):

Try this and Check [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)

copy your file to a directory.

cd directory

```
shutil.make_archive('gzipped', 'gztar', os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 1):

@CommonSense had a good answer, but the file will always be created zipped inside its parent directories. If you need to create a zipfile without the extra directories, just use the `zipfile` module directly

```
import os, zipfile
inpath  = "test.txt"
outpath = "test.zip"
with zipfile.ZipFile(outpath, "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    zf.write(inpath, os.path.basename(inpath))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing a file copy op:

```
def single_file_to_archive(full_path, archive_name_no_ext):
    tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    shutil.copy2(full_path, tmp_dir)
    shutil.make_archive(archive_name_no_ext, "zip", tmp_dir, '.')
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Archiving a directory to another destination was a pickle for me but [shutil.make_archive not zipping to correct destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741490/shutil-make-archive-not-zipping-to-correct-destination) helped a lot.

```
from shutil import make_archive
make_archive(
    base_name=path_to_directory_to_archive},
    format="gztar",
    root_dir=destination_path,
    base_dir=destination_path)
```