# shutil.make_archive not zipping to correct destination

Tags: python-3.x, zip, shutil

As per the code below I am having issues with the zipping a directory using the python 3 shutil.make_archive function. The .testdir will be zipped but it is being zipped in /home/pi, instead of /home/pi/Backups.

```
zip_loc = '/home/pi/.testdir'
zip_dest = '/home/pi/Backups/'
shutil.make_archive(zip_loc, 'zip', zip_dest)
```

Could anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reading the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) I came up with:

```
zip_loc = '/home/pi/.testdir'
zip_dest = '/home/pi/Backups/'
shutil.make_archive(base_dir=zip_loc, root_dir=zip_loc, format='zip', base_name=zip_dest)
```

From the docs:

> *base_name* is the name of the file to create, including the path, minus any format-specific extension.

> *root_dir* is a directory that will be the root directory of the archive; for example, we typically chdir into *root_dir* before creating the archive.

> *base_dir* is the directory where we start archiving from; i.e. *base_dir* will be the common prefix of all files and directories in the archive.

> *root_dir* and *base_dir* both default to the current directory.

Comment: base_name should add dest path

Answer (score -1):

Before to write the archive, move to the good directory :

```
old_path = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(path)
```

-> write the archive

After writing the archive move back to old directory :

```
os.chdir(old_path)
```