# Writing opencv image to zip file in python

Tags: python, opencv, zip

I have an opencv image:

```
img = cv2.imread(filename)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0.15)
```

now I want to write it directly into zip

```
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('out.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zipf.write(...)
```

Guess it's something to do with [`cv2.imencode()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga461f9ac09887e47797a54567df3b8b63) but not sure.
Can you help? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer:

```
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('out.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
retval, buf = cv2.imencode('.png', img)
zipf.writestr(name_in_zip, buf)
```

works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can find answers to your question under this link:
[stackoverflow.com/questions/30049201/how-to-compress-a-file-with-shutil-make-archive-in-python/45711390](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049201/how-to-compress-a-file-with-shutil-make-archive-in-python/45711390)

Comment: it's for the general case, but i wanted to know how to do it for opencv images specifically.